# idea to add javascript array to database using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

i need to push data in javascript array into database using PHP

first i have multidimentional array in js.

```
Brady [0] [0] = "1";
Brady [0] [1] = "Carol";
Brady [1] [0] = "2";
Brady [1] [1] = "Jan";
Brady [2] [0] = "3";
Brady [2] [1] = "Mike";
```

and i have table in database such as (id, name)

second if i need to delete some rows in array before i added how can i do?

third how can i push it to database after i delete data in array?

Comment: Have you got anything already or do you simply have no idea where to start? Do you know enough PHP/SQL to put something into a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must know the basics of [AJAX](http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-ajax.html) concept. Parameter passing of its your own interest either

1. separate items

   ex:  `xmlHttpReq.open('GET', "/test.json&day=" + day + "&month=" + month + "&year=" + year, true);`
2. concat array as a string with special character and send ,parse it at backend

   ex:

   string sample=array[0]+'|'+array[1](http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-ajax.html)....

   ```
      xmlHttpReq.open('GET', "/test.json&arrtest=" +sample , true);
   ```

   at backend use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) string to make it as array again.

Answer (score 6):

Pass it to PHP as a JSON-encoded string, let PHP reconstruct it as a PHP array using `json_decode()`, and then just treat it like a normal PHP array.